# FuelPHP Cache-control and Expied

Tags: ios, azure, caching, centos

I dont know how to where i should start from.
So, pleaes forgive me if I'm asking wrong question.

I have an iOS app. The app request to an API of CentOS server which using FuelPHP to get list of data. Also, we are using CDN to cache the data (Azure -Verizon)

When I get respond header, I saw that :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = ": X-Requested-With";
   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = ": post, get, origins";
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = ": *";
   "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, must-revalidate";
   Connection = close;
   "Content-Type" = "application/json";
   Date = "Mon, 13 Mar 2017 07:13:01 GMT";
   Expires = "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT";
   Pragma = "no-cache";
   Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)";
   "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
   "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.32
```

What should I do to make Cache-Control become max-age=xxx?

what I want is to cache the data via CDN of window Aruze Verizon.

Please help, If my question is not clear, please guide me, i will provide mor information.

Comment: This question does not appear to be fuelPHP related

Comment: @paullb: the API is running on FuelPHP server code, why it does not relate? also the respond header must be set by FuelPHP code, right?

Comment: You mentioned Fuelphp, CDN and a variety of other things. What what is the code that is generating this output?

Comment: There is an API of CentOS server which using FuelPHP. I have already mentioned.